# Git am did not apply all the changes

Tags: git, patch

I have received some patches to apply to a repo and to do this I do

```
git am <  the_patch.patch
```

Sadly it generated an error. I checked the error and applied the changes that the error cited my self. (for some reason it couldn't apply some simple changes)

then I did `git am --resolved` and I could see the new commit

Then I did the same for the next patch and alas, again an error
So I checked the error and it was about changing some external variable so I edited my self.

But that was the only error, which was fishy because nowhere I defined that variable (the patch must surely do!- I thought) so I did `git am --continue` and the commit was generated!

Still fishy! so I went to another place that the patch modified and *it was not modified!*- erg am did not applied the rest of the patch!

How can I correct this?

Right now the only thing I can think is to check and apply one by one all the changes!

EDIT: I just checked and when manually correcting git am errors, git am does not proceed to continue the patch. What is the **correct** way to use git am and apply patches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to understand `git am` is to start by understanding `git apply`.

The `git apply` command takes one patch—which can affect some or all of your files—and attempts to apply it to the current checkout.  It does not make a new commit on its own, ever; sometimes it fails to apply the patch.  When it *does* fail to apply the patch, you can have it *partially*-apply the patch, using `--reject`, but you must still correct all problems yourself, and then do your own `git commit` from the final result.

This is mostly straightforward so far.  Remember that if the patch *doesn't* apply in some way, what this means is that **the patch itself is wrong for your software**.  Git does not understand your software.  Git simply applies some simple text-editing rules.  This means that even if the patch *does* apply, it could still be wrong for your software!  All we know for sure is that if it does *not* apply, it is *definitely* wrong—maybe not in any important way, but definitely wrong.  So you must use your own judgment here.

Now that you understand how each individual patch is handled, we can go on to `git am`.  The `git am` command *uses* `git apply`, in the following way:

- The input to `git am` is expected to be a "mailbox" file, containing multiple email messages.
- Each email message is expected to be the output from `git format-patch` or similar.  This means it contains some of the appropriate metadata for a new commit (author, date, and commit message in particular), plus a patch.
- The patch is handed to `git apply`.  This `git apply` command is run with `--reject` *if* you run `git am` with `--reject`, or run without `--reject` otherwise.

When `git apply` succeeds, `git am` uses the commit message to make a commit, and goes on to the next email message in the mailbox file.  When `git apply` fails—for any reason—`git am` writes continuation state to a hidden directory within the hidden `.git` directory and stops with its own failure (and a message that it stopped without completing).

With `git apply` having stopped here, your job is the same as if you were using `git apply` yourself.  If you did not use `--reject`, you must hand-apply *the entire patch*.  If you did use `--reject`, you must hand-apply *all the rejected patches*.  We already know, because `git apply` failed, that the patch is *wrong for your software*, so you must use a great deal of judgment here.

Once you have hand-applied the patch and ensured that any inconsistencies are fixed, you may then run `git am --continue` or any of its other two spellings (`git am --resolved`, `git am -r`).  The `am` command will now use the metadata from the patch to make a new commit, using whatever files you have left for it.  It *completely ignores the failed patch itself* (since *you* applied it), but does use the failed patch's author and message to make the commit.  It then moves on to the next message in the mailbox file as usual.

It looks like your main mistake was assuming that the per-patch `git apply` behaved as if it were run with `--reject`, when that is not the default.

Comment: I have two questions here: 1. You are saying that if `--reject` is not used, as soon as `git am` fails, and even though I apply the rejected change, it will just skip the rest? That is surprising and actually what is happening! I suppose I should try `--reject`

Comment: the second thing is that, I used `git apply` instead of `am` and this time it applied everything without a problem. Obviously I had to made the commits (which totally erased the name of the original commiters) but no error occurred. How could this be explained?

Comment: 1: No, but the *entire patch* is ignored; you must hand-apply the whole thing before using `--continue`. With `--reject`, you must hand-apply just the rejected parts (in the `.rej` files) before using `--continue`. 2: It's not really clear to me what's going on at this point. Perhaps `git am` is set up to default to `--no-3way` and you ran `git apply` with  `-3` or `--3way`. Or, maybe one of the later patches set things up so that the earlier patch applied. Without having the exact files, I can only guess at these things.

Answer (score 0):

Use directory redirect flag --directory= < where you want to apply patch that folder > /path/0001mypatch.patch

$ git am -3 -k  --directory= < where you want to apply patch that folder > /path/0001mypatch.patch